# redux-observable dispatch actions

Tags: redux, redux-observable

I need to dispatch some actions in some order using `redux-observable` however, it takes just last action to dispatch. Please see example:

```
export const fetchClientsEpic = (action$, { dispatch }) =>
  action$
    .ofType(fetchClients)
    .mapTo(fetchClientsPending(true))
    .mergeMap(() => {
      return ajax
        .getJSON('some/get/clients/api')
        .map((clients: IClient[]) => {
          return fetchClientsSuccess(
            map(clients, (client, index) => ({
              key: index,
              ...client,
            })),
          );
        });
    });
```

`fetchClientsSuccess` is dispatched with clients but `fetchClientsPending` not, I totally do not get it why. I could use `dispatch` because I get it in params, but I feel it is not good solution(?). It should be done in the stream I guess. I am starting with RxJs and redux-observable. Is it possible to do?

Comment: I was able to split it to separate epics and create new action:

`const fetchClientsEpic = (action$) =>  action$    .ofType(fetchClients)    .mergeMap(() => [fetchClientsPending(true), fetch()]);`
pending modify the store, and fetch just fetching data and set it to the srtore. But still I am not sure if it can be optimized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operators are chains of Observables where the input of one stream is the output of another. So when you use `mapTo` you're mapping one action to the other. But then your `mergeMap` maps that Pending action and maps it to that other inner Observable that does the ajax and such, effectively throwing the Pending action away. So think of RxJS as a series of pipes where data flows through (a stream)

While there is no silver bullet, in this particular case what you want to achieve can be done by using `startWith` at the end of your inner Observable

```
export const fetchClientsEpic = (action$, { dispatch }) =>
  action$
    .ofType(fetchClients)
    .mergeMap(() => {
      return ajax
        .getJSON('some/get/clients/api')
        .map((clients: IClient[]) => {
          return fetchClientsSuccess(
            map(clients, (client, index) => ({
              key: index,
              ...client,
            })),
          );
        })
        .startWith(fetchClientsPending(true)); // <------- like so
    });
```

This is in fact the same thing as using `concat` with `of(action) first`, just shorthand.

```
export const fetchClientsEpic = (action$, { dispatch }) =>
  action$
    .ofType(fetchClients)
    .mergeMap(() => {
      return Observable.concat(
        Observable.of(fetchClientsPending(true)),
        ajax
          .getJSON('some/get/clients/api')
          .map((clients: IClient[]) => {
            return fetchClientsSuccess(
              map(clients, (client, index) => ({
                key: index,
                ...client,
              })),
            );
          })
      );
    });
```

---

That said, I would recommend against synchronously dispatching another action to set the state that fetching is pending and instead rely on the original `fetchClients` action itself for the same effect. It should be assumed by your reducers that if such an action is seen, that some how the fetching still start regardless. This saves you the boilerplate and helps a bit on micro-perf since you don't need to run through the reducers, epics, and rerender twice.

There's no rules though, so if you feel strongly about this, go for it :)

Comment: Thanks for good clarification. Could I use .concatAll()` after `.mergeMap` instead of `Observable.concat` (of course `mergeMap`, this case returns array of Observables)? Which approach you reccomend?