# Dispatch multiple actions from in redux-observable

Tags: redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I am trying to dispatch multiple actions to redux. Here is my code

```
 action$.pipe(
    ofType(trigger),
    mergeMap(({ payload }) =>
      from(endpoint(payload)).pipe(
        map(response =>

          // this works fine
          // setData(response.data)

          // this doesn't
          concat(
            of(setData(response.data)),
            of({ type: 'hello' })
          )

          // I also tried
          [
            of(setData(response.data)),
            of({ type: 'hello' })
          ]

        )
      )
    ),

    catchError(err => Promise.resolve(creators.setError(err)))
  )
```

Single dispatch works, but if I try multiple items as above I am getting `Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dispatch multiple actions with redux-observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56509064/dispatch-multiple-actions-with-redux-observable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map` just maps one item to another so when you return `[action1, action2]` you're still returning an array and `redux-observable` tries to treat it as an action itself. What you want instead is "unwrapping" the array (or Observable created with `concat`) returned.

So instead of using `map` you can use `mergeMap` (or `concatMap`) and when you return an array it'll iterate it and make separate emissions for each item:

```
mergeMap(response => [
  setData(response.data),
  { type: 'hello' },
]),
```

If this looks too odd you can wrap the array with `from` to make it more obvious:

```
mergeMap(response => from([
  setData(response.data),
  { type: 'hello' },
])),
```

You can even use a single `of`:

```
mergeMap(response => of(
  setData(response.data),
  { type: 'hello' },
)),
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I spent a day trying to figure it out. `mergeMap` is what I was missing.

Comment: switchMap could work as an alternative in some cases. switchMap(() => [action1, action2])